# Не работает mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица users, в ней две колонки - id и login. Для примера, первая запись - id 1, login 7433. Нужно через форму принять значение логина и на его основе делать всякие действия. Значение логина записывается в переменную $playerNumber. С этим вроде все нормально. Пишу запрос:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$playerNumber'");
if ($query) {
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    ...всякие действия, вывод нужных записей...
}
```

Как писать нужные мне действия я вроде понимаю, но выводится не та информация, которая нужна (но то, что она вообще выводится - это хорошо, хотя бы коннект с базой работает). Проверяла, добавляя var_dump($result) после третьей строчки в примере выше, пишет - bool(false). Может, у кого есть какие мысли, почему mysql_fetch_array не пишет в $result?

Comment: $playerNumber точно содержит нужный логин?
Попробуйте еще убрать блок WHERE и посмотреть что возвращается

Comment: Попробуйте так $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE login=`".$playerNumber."`");

Comment: А если сделать так? while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    var_dump($row);
}. Напишите, что выводит var_dump

Comment: Проверьте вернулась ли выборка не пустой. echo mysql_num_rows($query);

Comment: Когда убираю WHERE, возвращается первая строка из таблицы - так вроде и должно быть? Пишет [0]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(4) "7433" ["login"]=> string(4) "7433" - значит, $playerNumber принимает нужное значение, когда я в форму ввожу логин 7433, но с WHERE выборка и правда пустая возвращается...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да бросьте вы уже mysql-расширение. Оно устарело и даже удалено из новых версий PHP.

При изучении PHP используйте документацию PHP, она очень неплохая и переведена на русский язык. Документация находится на сайте php.net, зайдите в описание функции [mysql_query](http://php.net/mysql_query). Первое что бросается в глаза -- предупреждение о том, что функция устарела и использовать её не надо. Кроме того, предлагается две альтернативы mysqli и PDO.

Интерфейс mysqli похож на интерфейс mysql-расширения и возможно вам будет проще начать с него. Открывайте ссылку [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php), прочитайте описание и загляните в примеры использования. Там будут ответы на самые первые ваши вопросы!

Когда вы разберётесь как делать запросы к базе данных и обрабатывать полученные результаты, обязательно обратите внимание на то, что подставлять неэкранированные значения в SQL-запрос опасно. Погуглите `SQL-инъекция`.

Конкретно в вашем случае `false` означает, что ничего не найдено по вашему запросу. Убедитесь что он составлен верно сделайте `var_dump("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$playerNumber'");`

Comment: Заработало с mysqli! Написала $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$playerNumber'"; if ($query) {$result = mysqli_query($link, $query); $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);var_dump($row);} - выводится строка с нужным логином :) Спасибо!